# AWS EC2 - allow traffic to server/site through public IP, SSL certificate issues

Tags: networking, ssl, https, wordpress

We have a Wordpress site which serves as the company intranet. We need to allow an external user to access the wp-login page and subsequently the wp-admin dashboard to manage the site. Would like to avoid any VPN's or internal connectivity to accomplish this, as that would require a domain account for RADIUS, and this person isn't on the domain;

In EC2, I added an inbound rule to the security group assigned to this instance to allow inbound traffic from this person's public IP. This allows me to access the wp-login page from external as follows:

```
https://{public_IP_of_EC2_instance}/wp-login.php
```

However, upon logging in this way, I am not then allowed access to the wp-admin dashboard.
I receive an error in the browser:

```
"This site can't provide a secure connection"
intranet.companyname.com sent an invalid response. 
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I should note 2 things:
When logging into wp-login.php through the public IP, I'm greeted by one of those "This site is not secure" browser pages where you need to click "advanced options" and choose to "proceed anyways". This would be fine, if the website continued to work after login.

The response from the webpage does not come from the public IP of the host after login to wp-login.php, instead the response comes from the websites FQDN "intranet.companyname.com".

The site "intranet.companyname.com" does have a valid SSL certificate issued, with a common name of "*.companyname.com".

I'm guessing this is why things work when accessing the site via "intranet.companyname.com", however not when trying to access via https://{public_IP}/wp-login.php.
Additionally, the site does not work when trying to access via normal http (not https).

Can anybody suggest a quick fix for this? Perhaps a way to allow normal http connections?

EDIT - further investigation shows that the WP site has a plugin "Really Simple SSL" installed. Trying to see if this can be re-configured to allow http connections, or to allow https:// to the public IP and not re-direct to https://intranet.companyname.com

Thank you